# What is the best way to distribute reusable JavaScript modules with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, module, amd, commonjs

There are many ways to format JavaScript modules: AMD, CommonJS, UMD, ES6, global script.  I've seen projects that structure their source code in whatever way they want and run a build process to generate a dist directory containing code in all the above formats.  This has the advantage that the user of the code can just pick whichever format is most applicable to his environment.

This method works fine as long as the module has no dependencies on other modules.  In the case where the modules must import other modules, there are implied complications.  For example RequireJS uses a config file that looks like:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'js/lib/jquery',
        'ember': 'js/lib/ember',
        'handlebars': 'js/lib/handlebars',
        'underscore': 'js/lib/underscore'
    }
});
```

Other loaders have equivalent mechanisms for mapping import paths.

If jQuery is a dependency, should the module import it from the path 'jquery'?  What if the system in which it is being incorporated stores jQuery at the path 'libs/jquery'?  In this case, is it the responsibility of the author of the system incorporating jQuery to provide aliases in the configuration of the import path?

This questioning strongly suggests that a truly reusable module must provide code formatted in all module formats as well as document clearly upon what libraries (and versions thereof) it depends and document what import paths at which those libraries are assumed to exist.

For example I could author a fancy jQuery plugin that I distribute in AMD, CommonJS, ES6, and global variations.  I would document that this plugin depends on jQuery version 2.0 imported through the path 'jquery_on_a_path_that_confuses_you'.  The would-be user of this plugin must copy the plugin into his project and then configure his module loader or build tool to export jQuery at the path 'jquery_on_a_path_that_confuses_you'.

As far as I can tell:

- There is no standard for what to use for import paths.
- There is no standard way to express the dependency, version, and import path requirements to the user of a piece of code.
- There is no standard remedy to deal with clashing import paths or load multiple versions of a library.

Does there exist any plan to deal with this strange arrangement?  To me it seems a little crazy to have module systems that don't know how to name their modules.  Am I wrong?

Comment: There's no standard way to define way, but you can use tools that helps you with this. A Bower package, express all the dependeces of a lib/framework, and when you install it, the Bower will manage the versions for you (including the path).
With RequireJS you can load diferent versions of a same lib, because when you import using the 'define' function, will be injected into a isolated scope.

P.S. Sorry for my english! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [jspm.io + SystemJS](http://jspm.io/) which is a relatively new package manager and universal module loader which is increasing in popularity.

Please find below some presentations and article on the subject I found useful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXzQP38mdnE,

https://vimeo.com/65042246,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szJjsduHBQQ,

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/11/js-modules-jspm-systemjs/

Answer (score 0):

Late with the answer, but if you're after writing plain JS code (without jQuery or other frameworks), I've found that there's the [deploader.js](https://github.com/MikeSpock/dljs) repo, which you can use to wrap any kind of JS into modules and do dependency loading.

May worth checking out.

Comment: The provided link is not available.